# JasperReports servlet dependencies

Tags: tomcat, servlets, dependencies, jasper-reports

I'd like to deploy a JasperReport to be generated by a servlet. I've found example of code for such a servlet but am unsure of what the minimum dependencies are which need to be added to Tomcat.   I'm not using the JasperReports viewer or other add-ons so I just want to know the minimum jar files that I need to add to /lib without having to go through trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your report does and where it gets the data from.  You obviously need teh jasper reports jar, if there are charts you probably need jfreechart.  If it uses any other fonts it will need the fonts jar.  You probably wil need the relevant JDBC driver (or other datasource libraries.  Any extensions you have created or use.  Do you use groovy as the report language, if so you need that.  Then there are other things that may be already there that you may need, such as commons-XXX.  Even after all that there is extra stuff dependant on your output, batik for svg, excel libraries, etc.

You may wish to look at using maven, it can simplify this so much, even if you don;t want it to create the files to deploy it will at least allow you to list the dependencies automatically

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I did some searching and found a list of dependencies on installationwiki.  Here's the link in case anyone else comes across this post.  http://www.installationwiki.org/JasperReports